# problem getting hook_menu() to work

Tags: routes

I want to display a button on the front page of my website and for the first time (as beginner), I wanted the link to be configured in the administration page. I followed [the tutorial on creating a module configuration](https://www.drupal.org/node/206761) and the code I wrote doesn't seem to show a textfield while visiting admin/config/content/linkpresent.

```
/**
 * fonction permettant de gérer le lien de la bannière du front
 */
function mij_page_presentation() {
  return 'hello world';
}

/**
 * function in admin pages
 */
function mij_page_admin() {
  $form = array ();
  $form ['mij_page_presentation'] = array (
      '#type'   => 'textfield',
      '#title'  => t('Lien renvoyant vers la page de présentation '),
      '#size' => '255',
      '#default_value'  => '',
      '#description' => t('Ici est renseigné le lien renvoyant vers la page de présentation '),
      '#required' =>TRUE,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

/**
 * implements hook_menu
 */
function mij_page_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/content/linkpresent']=array(
      'title' => 'Lien de la page de présentation',
      'description'=>'Ici est renseigné le lien renvoyant vers la page de présentation ',
      'page callback'=> 'drupal_get_form',
      'access arguments' => array('administer mij_page settings'),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

function mij_page_admin_validate($form, &$form_state){
  $presentation = $form_state['values']['mij_page_presentation'];
  if(is_numeric($presentation)){
    form_set_error('mij_page_presentation',t('veuillez entrer une URL relative valide'));
  }
}
```

Here is the blank page I obtain in the administration page.

[image]

Anyone has an idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `page arguments` are missing, so Drupal doesn't know what form to load.

Change your hook_menu implementation to this:

```
function mij_page_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/content/linkpresent']=array(
      'title' => 'Lien de la page de présentation',
      'description'=>'Ici est renseigné le lien renvoyant vers la page de présentation ',
      'page callback'=> 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('mij_page_admin'),
      'access arguments' => array('administer mij_page settings'),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Remember to clear Drupal's caches after you make the change.

Comment: Perfect ! It is working. I can't validate your answer for now (have to wait 3 more minutes).
I have one more question : How can i keep the data I enter in the textfield and how to get it in my code to use it elsewhere ?

Comment: Because you're using a system settings form the data will be stored automatically - you can get it anywhere in code with `variable_get('mij_page_presentation', 'default_value');`